# TestFlight support for android

Tags: android, events, logging, crash, testflight

I have developed app in android. I have done integration with testFlight for crashes, logs and events.But now as testFlight has stopped a support for android.  So If i have submitted my build to play store, will it continue to support and give information that it was giving before or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received response from TestFlight and they have said it won't affect to current app that is on play store